# Python -- Pack Several Objects?

Tags: python

Is it possible to 'pack' a `python` object (say, a `list` or a `dict`) to a variable rather than to a file?

Ideally, I'd like to 'pack' a couple of different dictionaries, lists etc, and only then, 'concatenate' all the 'packed' info and save it in an external file (say, in a binary format).

Is it doable?

Comment: Forget the "packing" concept.  That's not helpful.  You can trivially "serialize" or "pickle" any and all Python objects into files without introducing extra (and ill-defined) concepts.  Just read up on "object serialization" and rephrase your question to state what you can't figure out about JSON, Pickle or YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the pickle module. 
http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Comment: Thanks. From what I know, `pickle` supports *dumping* an object straight to a file. Does it allow `packing` an object to a variable (instead of dumping it to a file)? Ideally, I'd like to `pack` the info into a variable, and ONLY THEN write the packed object to a file.

Comment: @user yes, you can pickle an object into a string variable rather than to a file.  I've used it as a poor-man's `undo` operation before.

Comment: You can use the pickle.dumps to dump to a string. You could collect a list of dumps then dump the whole thing to a file, or come up with any level of abstraction.

Comment: goldsz, thanks, that's what I was looking for. Does `pickle.dumps` dump only the DATA of an object, or also the structure, methods etc?

Comment: @user3262424: The documentation on pickle is quite clear.  It helps to read them carefully so you know what it pickles and doesn't pickle.  A class definition is -- generally -- not pickled, it's required to unpickle the data.

Answer (score 2):

See the `json` module.  http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

You can serialize objects with JSON.